# Finding Unique Linear Maps with Specific Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Setup:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $F$-vector space and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Show that there exist $T,S:V\rightarrow V$ such that $R(S)=W$ and $N(T)=W$.

**My thoughts so far:** Off the bat, it seems like we should define functions whose range and null space have these properties and then check that they are linear. For example, let $S(v)=v$ if $v\in W$ and let $S(v)=0$ otherwise. By construction, $R(S)=W$, but we run into some problems when checking if $S$ is linear. Namely, take $v,w\in (V-W)$. Then, we know nothing about $S(v+w)$ since we don't know whether $v+w$ is in $V-W$ or in $W$.

How then should I go about searching for these linear maps? (A complete answer to the problem is not necessary, but a push in the right direction is appreciated.)

Edit: $R(S)$ denotes the range of $S$ and $N(T)$ denotes the null space of $T$.

Comment: What are $R$ and $N$?

Comment: @user7530 the range and nullspace, respectively. I'll add that in for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is finite dimensional, you can define a basis of the space $W$ quite easily and can extend this to a basis of $V$, so that $W = span\{b_1,\cdots , b_m\}$ and $V = span\{b_1, \cdots, b_m, \cdots, b_m \}$, where we say that the dimension of $W$ and $V$ are $m$ and $n$ respectively. What can you say about the action of $T$ and $S$ on these basis? Note that linear maps are essentially defined by their action on the basis vectors. What should $T(b_i)$ be for $i = 1 ,\cdots , m$, what about $S(b_i)$?. Since you are looking for the existence of a map with the properties you listed, you can define the action of $T$ and $S$ on their images and linearity should follow. From your title, I see you mention uniqueness, which you should clarify.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I see now that we should take $T(b_i)=0$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ and $T(b_i)=b_i$ otherwise. Then, we might deconstruct a vector into its representation as a combination of basis vectors in order to see how $T$ affects it?